# How can I convert a C# list into something that's hashable?

Tags: c#, list, hash

I want something along the lines of Python's tuples (or, for sets, frozensets), which are hashable. I have a `List<String>` which is most certainly not hashing correctly (i.e. by value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to define your own container, possibly wrapping the List, to get useful semantics for equality-hash-equals (GetHashCode and Equals). You could even make the wrapper conform to IList if you like.

To avoid mutability issues and a changing GetHashCode/Equals results (which would make use of your new object in a hashing Dictionary problematic!) you should also provide some kind of guard (perhaps make a copy of the input upon creation of your type) and/or document the constraints.

You can use [SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) to implement Equals rather trivially, but you'll need to implement a GetHashCode in a relevant way -- a simple method is a shifting XOR of the GetHashCode of each element.

Alternatively, if this is just used in a single Dictionary you can supply a custom [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) and avoid creating a wrapped type: [Dictionary constructor overload](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx).

It depends what your final goals are and there very well already be such wrapping containers :-)

Note: In .NET4 there is a set of [Tuple<...> classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) which override GetHashCode and Equals. See [cadenza](http://www.gitorious.org/cadenza) as the 3rd party alternative for prior .NET versions.